# Am I using findFragmentByTag Correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

My activity creates fragments dynamically and they are not created right off the start(hidden). So I need to basically be able to identify my fragments so I can send data to and from them from my activity. I keep getting a null object reference when trying to call a fragment's function (addAthleteToList)  from my main activity. Says my athlete object is null Am I identifying(creating) my fragment references correctly? Thanks

If not, how do I create tags for my fragments?

Main Activity function that sends data to fragment B (AthletesList):

```
 // Interface function
 // Sends athlete information to athlete list

@Override
public void send(Athlete athlete) {
    Log.e("", "Main Activity: " + athlete.getFirstName());
    AthletesList athletesList = (AthletesList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("athleteList");

    ArrayList<String> athleteEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
    athleteEvents = athlete.getEvents();

    for(int i = 0; i < athleteEvents.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("", "Athlete Event: " + athleteEvents.get(i).toString());
        switch (athleteEvents.get(i).toString()){
            case "4 x 400":
                athletesList.addAthleteToList(athlete, 1);
                break;
            case "1-Mile":
                break;
            case "100-Meter":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment A:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnAddAthlete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Athlete athlete = new Athlete();
            athlete.setFirstName(editFirstName.getText().toString());
            athlete.setLastName(editLastName.getText().toString());
            athlete.setAge(Integer.parseInt(editAge.getText().toString()));
            athlete.setEvents(athleteEvents);
            athlete.setGrade(editGrade.getText().toString());
            athlete.setTier(Integer.parseInt(editTier.getText().toString()));

            Log.e("", "Athlete Name: " + athlete.getFirstName() + " " + athlete.getLastName());

            AthletesList athletesList = new AthletesList();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, athletesList, "athletesList").commit();
            // interface sends athlete to main activity
            communicator.send(athlete);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `FragmentTag` value is different

**Set Tag shows "athletesList"**

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, athletesList, "athletesList").commit();
```

**Get Tag shows "athleteList"**

```
AthletesList athletesList = (AthletesList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("athleteList");
```

`athletesList!=athleteList`, therefore your `findFragmentByTag` returns `null`.

for a better solution, create a public field constant that you can use to tag your fragment, such as :

`public static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_ATHLETELIST = "tag_athletelist";`

then use it as the `fragmentTag` :

**SET**

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, athletesList, TAG_FRAGMENT_ATHLETELIST).commit();
```

**GET**

```
AthletesList athletesList = (AthletesList) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_ATHLETELIST);
```